# Pass form data containing ampScript/html snippets?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage

Is it possible to create a form on a landing page where the input field/text area could possibly have ampscript and html code, such as

```
Hello, %%=v(@first_name)=%%!<br>Welcome to LA.
```

and write that input to a data extension right from the cloudpage?

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, yes.

You really only need to watch out for your form validation and also realize that it may become encoded by the browser when posting - so special characters may be lost to the HTML entity equivalent.

E.g. '<' would become '`&lt;`'

I would be very careful when doing this as many different browsers handle and interpret this differently and can potentially corrupt your data. Also, when displaying this content you may need to do some decoding and/or replaces to get the right format/info. The more the info is passed around, the more convoluted it will get.

I would not recommend this for a long term solution, but it is a possibility for the short term.

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington for your answer. How would you recommend passing the data. I have tried putting the UpdateData ampscript inside of an "onClick" function but realized ampscript is server side language and executed only on page load. The only other option I know is to pass the data to another page to execute the update ampscript. The issue with that is how can I pass the ampscript and/or html snippets without placing them in the url because that will break the link.

Comment: Is the page hosted on SFMC?  If so. Have the form post to itself and collect the info Server Side via the RequestParameter() function and then Update.

Comment: I gave that a try and it works for ampscript like %%=v(@name)=%% but a simple < br > crashes the update.

Comment: you may need to force a URLEncode on it and then decode it when you pull.  E.g. set a ReplaceList(ReplaceList(@yourcontent, '<', '&lt;'), '>', '&gt;')

Comment: %%[
set @ val1 = RequestParameter("name")
 set@ val2 = RequestParameter("welcome")

if @ val2 != "" Then
    set @ person = lookupRows("People", "Name", @ name)
 if rowCount(@ person) == 1 then
         UpdateData("People", 1, "Name", @ name, "Welcome Text", @ val2)
  endif
endif
 ]%%<br> That is the ampScript I used to update but I think its crashing when the form is collecting the input and it contains html

Comment: I'll read up on URLEncode, I'm not going to give up. Thank you for your help!

Comment: also - you have a space in your variable, which could be causing issues. '@ person' should be '@person'.  Do you have the error message you are receiving?

Comment: That was necessary to post a comment, otherwise the forum thought i was trying to tag someone. In my code it is '@person'.

Comment: Gotcha. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: One last thing, Im reading URLEncoding which is pretty cool, but Im trying to understand when I would decode. Are you suggesting that the data get written to the data extension in URLEncode format (<br> would be written as "%3Cbr%3E") and whenever I am pulling from that data extension I would decode?

Comment: yes that is correct.  There are other options, but that is the simplest for short term.